# How to run indicator-remindor at login?

Tags: indicator, .desktop, autostart

I installed `indicator-remindor` in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system. The program seems to work properly although some warning related to the lack of the ‍`/gtk-fallback.css‍` library appear at start up.

Is there any method to run indicator-remindor at login?

- I tried to use the Startup Application of Ubuntu without any result.
- I also tried to run a script just containing indicator-remindor as a command, using the `.bash_login`. Again no results.

Interestingly when the shell is on if I open an xterm and write

```
source .bash_login
```

the indicator-remindor starts!

Comment: What did you put into the script and into Startup applications?

Comment: the script is simply   indicator-remindor

Comment: in the Startup application I selected the indicator-remindor.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I discovered where the problem was. I'm using Cinnamon as a launcher and for some reasons I cannot understand, the startup file `indicator-remindor.desktop` which is in the `~/.config/autostart` directory does not work properly.

I modified this file following that of Alarm Clock:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Name=Alarm Clock
Exec=indicator-remindor
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

Now all works.

Comment: Would you accept you own answer as it works for you.